# Samsung GS3 (SPH-i710) exchange server repeated security update notification

Tags: email, security, exchange, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I just connected my Samsung Galaxy S 3 (SPH-i710) to my exchange email server at work. It synced up and my email and calendars show on my device, however every few minutes I get a notification that says "Update Security Settings" when I click on it, it shows an alert dialog that says "Security Update Required" "Update Security Settings to use ". Clicking OK will allow my email box to refresh. However if I ignore the notification it won't receive push updates.

Does anybody know what the cause of this may be?

Answer (score 2):

Exchange is trying to apply your organization's default ActiveSync policy to your device.  More than likely, the refresh interval setting on the ActiveSync policy has a number set in hours.  Unchecking this box may resolve the issue.

We're having this issue with a couple of our Android devices after publishing a new ActiveSync policy.

Here is [Microsoft's official response](http://community.office365.com/en-us/wikis/exchange/2204.aspx) on the issue.